# Al ordenar un arreglo elimina datos

Tags: c, array, algoritmos, quicksort

Estoy programando un algortimo genetico para que este resuelva problemas de programacion lineal, estoy usando lenguaje C, al momneto de calcular el limite de las variables guardo los valores en un array tipo float, yo requiero ordenar ese array pero me borra un dato que necesito al momento de ordenarlo:
He usado un shell_sort pogramado por mi y el qsort que esta implementado en la líbreria estándar y con ambos me da el mismo resultado, anexo el código del algortimo que uso para ordenar y la funcion comparador que utilizo para el qsort():

```
void shell_sort(float *A, int n){
    int gap = n/2;  //Se obtiene el gap dividiendo el tamaño de arreglo entre dos
    int inner, outer, swap; //Variables auxiliares

    while (gap > 0) { //Mientras gap sea mayor que zero entonces:
        for(outer = gap; outer < n; outer++){ // Para outer igual a gap, siempre que outer sea menor a n, outer aumentara su valor en uno
            inner = outer; // inner se iguala al valor de outer
            swap = A[inner]; // Swap se iguala a la posiscion inner de A
            while (inner > gap - 1 && A[inner - gap] > swap ) {  // Mientras inner sea mayor que gap menos 1 y que A en su posicion inner menos gap sea mayor a Swap
                A[inner] = A[inner - gap]; //La posicion inner de A tomara como nuevo valor la posicion inner menos  gap de A
                inner -= gap; //inner decrementa su valor en gap veces
            }
            A[inner] = swap; //La posicion inner de A tomo como nuevo valor swap
        }
        gap /=2; // se divide a gap entre dos
    }
}
```

Salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int comp(const void * a, const void * b){
    if(*(float*)a < *(float*)b) return -1;
    if(*(float*)a == *(float*)b) return 0;
    if(*(float*)a > *(float*)b) return 1;
}
```

En la imagen se puden ver los datos antes de ordenarlos y despues de ordenarlos, como se observa falta el 0.000 
Funcion donde se usan los algortimos de ordenamiento:

```
Limites obtenerValoresLimites(lista *l,char var){
    Limites lim;
    restriccion r;
    int i,j;
    float *aux = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < Size(l); i++)
    {
        r = Element(l,i+1);
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(r.variables); j++)
        {
            if(r.variables[j] == var){
                aux[i] = (r.limite/r.coeficientes[j]);
                }
        }
    }

    //for (i = 0; i < sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux) ;i++)
        //printf("%f\n",aux[i]);


    //qsort(aux,sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux)+1,sizeof(float),comp);
    shell_sort(aux,sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux));

    //printf("\n");

    //for (i = 0; i < sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux) ;i++)
    //{
    //  printf("%f\n",aux[i]);
    //}

    lim.inferior = 0;
    lim.superior = aux[(sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux))-1];
    lim.variable = var;

    return lim;
}
```

Comment: Deberías incluir el código un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema... yo he probado la función y no me ha eliminado ningún valor... así que el error debe estar en el código que no has incluído.

Comment: La imagen que has incluido está como cortada. No se vé que es la entrada o la salida, y no se ve si falta o no el cero, a menos que los tres números de arriba sean la entrada y los dos de abajo la salida.

Comment: Se me paso, gracias por la observación,

Comment: Asi es lo primeros numeros son lo que entra al algortimo de ordenamineto y posteriormente es lo que me sale, desaparece el 0, aunque muy posiblemente el error este en como determino el tamaño del array.

Answer (score 1):

La primera en la frente:

```
float *aux = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
```

Estás reservando memoria para un único elemento de tipo `float`, luego esta otra instrucción:

```
aux[i] = (r.limite/r.coeficientes[j]);
```

... va a acceder a memoria que no está reservada para esta variable y aquí pueden suceder dos cosas:

- La memoria pertence a otras variables de tu aplicación y la misma se vuelve inestable (ya que pisas memoria)
- La memoria pertenece a otro proceso y, en función de si el Sistema Operativo es mínimamente moderno o no, o dejarás el sistema hecho unos zorros (SO antiguos) o el SO mata tu aplicación para evitarlo (SO nuevos).

Dado que desde el principio ya eres capaz de saber cuántos elementos necesitas tienes que hacer la reserva correcta:

```
int numElementos = Size(l);
float *aux = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*numElementos);
for (i = 0; i < numElementos; i++)
// ...

free(aux); // No olvides liberar la memoria!!!
```

Por otro lado, si esta es la forma que estabas usando para imprimir los valores del arreglo:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux) ;i++)
{
  printf("%f\n",aux[i]);
}
```

He de decirte que tienes un problema y es que `aux` no es un array de tamaño fijo sino que es un puntero que direcciona memoria dinámica... y `sizeof` se evalua en tiempo de compilación y, en este caso, te va a dar el tamaño de un puntero (32 o b4 bits) independientemente del número de elementos reservados.

Para las iteraciones tienes que usar `numElementos` o, en su defecto, `Size(l)`:

```
for (i = 0; i < numElementos ;i++)

// ...

shell_sort(aux,numElementos);
```

Por cierto, desde C99 es legal declarar variables dentro de los bucles, luego te recomendaría reducir la vida de cada variable al mínimo imprescindible:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numElementos ;i++)
```

Y si ahora echamos un vistazo a la función de ordenación vemos esto:

```
void shell_sort(float *A, int n){
  int swap;

  swap = A[inner];

  A[inner] = swap;
}
```

`swap` es de tipo `int` mientras que `A[inner]` es de tipo `float`. Al asignar un `float` a un `int` los decimales se pierden ya que `int` almacena números enteros. Si no quieres perder dichos decimales convierte `swap` a tipo `float`:

```
float swap;
```

Como no has puesto un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema no puedo validar la solución, pero como te dije vía comentarios, la función de ordenamiento no pisa valores, por lo que entiendo que con esta batería de cambios el programa debería empezar a funcionar correctamente.